# Regular expression for full match not partial

Tags: regex

I am currently trying to match the following

```
class-11/chemistry/
class-12/physics/
class-12/english
```

but not this

```
class-11/chemistry/physical-chemistry/
class-12/english/a-heart-of-ocean/
```

I could write up to here.

```
/^class-([12]{2})/([^/]+)/?/
```

But it matches partial which I don't want.

Comment: use the $ modifier at the end of your pattern - $ means the group must be at the end of the input

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i am using php language . To be more specific it is wordpress.

Comment: @stlawrance Did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close.

What you need is a `$` at the end which denotes the end of a string. Also escape the `/` by doing `\/`.

```
/^(class-([12]{2})\/([^\/]+))\/?$/
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/kI1kI5/3

Comment: Hai but it matching class-11/chemistry/physical-chemistry/ which is don't want :(

Comment: @stlawrance In my updated demo, you can test your strings one by one. It works.